# How to bind background of a column in silverlight during runtime?

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a grid with bunch of columns in it. To start with this grid is build during run time in the code behind and not much code in XAML except the generic grid, so I can't bind the column background during design time. I have been reading various blogs, questions and found the following as the closest answer.

```
SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
Binding b = new Binding("BackGroundColor");
b.Converter = new ColorConverterForReadOnly(); //This converter return color based on parameter
b.ConverterParameter = data;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(backgroundBrush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, b);
column.Background = backgroundBrush;
```

When I ran the code, the binding did not happen, I put a break point (in the first line) inside the converter to see if debug hits the converter at all and it did not hit the converter at all. If I would put

```
column.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
```

I can see the the column colors set to blue.

What am I missing in the binding that is not letting converter invoked?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding is targeting a "BackGroundColor" property.  For the binding to be hit, the DataContext of the column control would need to be an object that has a "BackGroundColor" property.

Comment: It make sense. In this context my column has Background which accept solidcolorbrush, any idea which property I might need to bind it to?